# OBIEE scorecard against SSAS returns an error

Tags: ssas, obiee

We are using OBIEE scorecards, we get this error with no sensible reason!

> Unresolved Connection Pool object: "BSC". [nQSError: 43113] Message returned from OBIS.

We connect OBIEE to SSAS. Is there anybody who knows the reason for this error.

Comment: Please describe this in more details. Questions seeking debugging help should contain enough details to reproduce the issue. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Does that connection pool object exist? Does the user have the correct privileges against it?